# ternary operator is not working as expected in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, conditional-operator

I have to render screens condition wise. but conditions are not getting fulfilled.

My function is always returns the false boolean value even if it doesn't have to.

Here is my code

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<bool> checkIsLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var data = await prefs.getString('isAuthenticated');

    // the value of data is true here
    print(data);
    if (data == "true") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkIsLoggedIn();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: checkIsLoggedIn() == true ? Profile() : LoginScreen());
        //error : checkIsLoggedin () function returns false in my case.
  }
}
```

Comment: `checkIsLoggedIn()` does not return a `bool` but `Future<bool>` which you need to await to extract the boolean value inside the `Future`. That is problematic for `build` since it cannot be `async`. But you can use a `FutureBuilder` to handle building the GUI which contains async logic: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `then()` to wait for the `Future`. Then, assign the result with `setState()`.

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<bool> checkIsLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var data = await prefs.getString('isAuthenticated');

    // the value of data is true here
    print(data);
    if (data == "true") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  var isLoggedIn = false; // HERE

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    checkIsLoggedIn().then((result) {  // HERE
      setState(() {
        isLoggedIn = result;
      });
     
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: isLoggedIn == true  // HERE
          ? Profile() 
          : LoginScreen());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When getting into problems, I do recommend you are first looking into the warnings you are getting around the problematic area. If you are using a default Flutter project, you should have the lint `unrelated_type_equality_checks` activated since it is part of the Core set of Dart Lints:

> **DON'T** Compare references of unrelated types for equality.
>
> Comparing references of a type where neither is a subtype of the other most likely will return **false** and might not reflect programmer's intent.

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unrelated_type_equality_checks.html

This would give the following warning in your IDE with a link to the documentation I linked to previously:

[image]

The problem is that your `checkIsLoggedIn()` method have the following signature which means it returns an object of the type `Future<bool>`:

```dart
Future<bool> checkIsLoggedIn() async {
```

And you are then comparing this against `true` which are of the type `bool`. If you are doing an equality check against these two different types, it will ALWAYS end up returning `false`, which is also what you are observing.

A `Future` also means that you are handling a value that are potentially still not created. So when you are running your `checkIsLoggedIn() == true` it does not even know yet if the `bool` inside your `Future<bool>` are `true` or `false`.

The solution are to either make it so `checkIsLoggedIn()` returns `bool`, which cannot be done in this case since the method are handling asynchronously logic.

Another solution would then be to `await` the returned `Future` from `checkIsLoggedIn()`. But we cannot use `await` unless we mark the method, we are inside, as `async`. But for Flutter, we are not allowed to have `build()` marked as `async`.

So a solution would instead be to handle the asynchronously nature of `checkIsLoggedIn()` by using `FutureBuilder`:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Which are a `Widget` made for handling the building of the GUI when we don't know the value of the `Future`, but then triggers an automatic rebuild when the value of the `Future` are received.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.getbool** instead **.getString**

To wait for checkIsLoggedIn result you can use a **FutureBuilder**.

Here an example :D

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<bool> checkIsLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final isAuthenticated = await prefs.getBool('isAuthenticated');

    return isAuthenticated;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: checkIsLoggedIn(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          // SHOW LOADING WHILE PREFS IS GETTING DATA
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          // SHOW SCREEN ACCORDING DATA
          return snapshot.data! //
              ? const Profile()
              : const LoginScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```